# cmake problem of target type when using swig with C++17

Tags: python, c++, cmake, swig

Things are getting confused for me, so I hope to be clear.

I made a c++17 library (called here `myLib`), and I bind it with python using swig. Everything is working when I compile by hand.
Now, I would like to automatize and clean my work using cmake: no problem for the library.

But things are getting more obscure to me when it comes to creating the binding with cmake.

I came with the following cmake sample:

```
include(FindSWIG)

find_program(SWIG_PATH swig)
find_package(SWIG 4.0 COMPONENTS python)

include(UseSWIG)

find_package(PythonLibs 3 REQUIRED)
find_package(PythonInterp ${PYTHONLIBS_VERSION_STRING} REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_SWIG_FLAGS -py3)

message("PYTHONLIBS_VERSION_STRING: ${PYTHONLIBS_VERSION_STRING}")
message("CMAKE_SWIG_FLAGS: ${CMAKE_SWIG_FLAGS}")

add_custom_target(
     binding_target
     )

include_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/external/include" "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include" ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
# If I use the following line instead to the previous, I get an error of target type non-compilable
# target_include_directories(binding_target "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/external/include" "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include" ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})


set_source_files_properties(py_myLib.i PROPERTIES CPLUSPLUS ON)

# If I use the following line, I get an error of target type non-compilable.
# target_compile_features(binding_target SHARED cxx_std_17)

swig_add_library(binding_target 
     TYPE SHARED 
     LANGUAGE python 
     SOURCES py_myLib.i
)
swig_link_libraries(binding_target ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES} USE_TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
```

With the previous code, the command `cmake ..` is exiting without error, but the compilation with `make` is returning errors as the compiler is not using the option `-std=c++17` to compile.
(by the way, I am wondering why `make` is compiling while `make binding_target` does nothing, I would expect the opposite.)

I tried to add a C++17 feature to the compilation with the line `target_compile_features` but then, I get an error from `cmake ..` about a `target_compile_features called with non-compilable target type`

So my question is: how can I build properly (inside a target) the swig binding with cmake
(precising the include directories and compilation option for this target) ?

Comment: It is `swig_add_library(binding_target)` which defines the target `binding_target` (unless `UseSWIG_TARGET_NAME_PREFERENCE` variable is set to LEGACY). Attempts to use that target before the command call are useless. And what is the reason of `add_custom_target(binding_target)` call, which creates the target with the same name?

Comment: Thank you for this precision. The use of `add_custom_target(binding_target)` was a misunderstanding. I though that I had to create the target before call `swig_add_library`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this solution (do not hesitate to improve it):

```
include(FindSWIG)

find_program(SWIG_PATH swig)
find_package(SWIG 4.0 COMPONENTS python)

include(UseSWIG)

find_package(PythonLibs 3 REQUIRED)
find_package(PythonInterp ${PYTHONLIBS_VERSION_STRING} REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_SWIG_FLAGS -py3)

message("PYTHONLIBS_VERSION_STRING: ${PYTHONLIBS_VERSION_STRING}")
message("CMAKE_SWIG_FLAGS: ${CMAKE_SWIG_FLAGS}")


# 
set_source_files_properties(py_myLib.i PROPERTIES CPLUSPLUS ON)
set_property(SOURCE py_myLib.i PROPERTY SWIG_MODULE_NAME py_myLib)
set (UseSWIG_TARGET_NAME_PREFERENCE STANDARD)

swig_add_library(py_myLib 
   TYPE SHARED 
   LANGUAGE python 
   SOURCES py_myLib.i
)

# For Swig wrapping
set_property(TARGET py_myLib PROPERTY SWIG_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES 
   "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/external/include" 
   "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include"
)

# For Cxx compilation
set_property(TARGET py_myLib PROPERTY INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES 
   "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/external/include" 
   "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include" 
   ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH}
)
set_property(TARGET py_myLib PROPERTY COMPILE_OPTIONS -shared -std=c++17 ) #

# swig_link_libraries( 
target_link_libraries( py_myLib
   ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES} 
) 

# 
target_include_directories(py_myLib
   PRIVATE
      # where the library itself will look for its internal headers
      ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include # 
      ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/external/include
   PUBLIC
      # where top-level project will look for the library's public headers
      $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
)
```